# React Boilerplate: substate.get is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is the same problem as [substate.get() is not a function using React Boilerplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880737/substate-get-is-not-a-function-using-react-boilerplate) but I am not getting what is the resolution of this problem.

I want to define my initial state at one file only. Is it a right way to initialize state.

In app.js I added

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  cloud: [
    {
      machine_name: 'trust.zscaler.net',
      domain: 'Zscaler.net',
        },
      ],
    });
const history = createHistory();
const store = configureStore(initialState, history);
```

In my container/selectors.js

```
const selectCloud = (state) => state.get('cloud');

const makeSelectCloudName = () => createSelector(
  selectCloud,
  (cloudState) => cloudState.get('domain')
);
```

In my container/index.js

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  cloud: makeSelectCloudName(),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCloud: (value) => {
    dispatch(setCloud(value));
  },
})

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'cloud', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'cloud', saga });
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(CloudSelect);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually direct selector to the cloud state domain

```
const selectCloud = (state) => state.get('cloud');
```

I think here you missed one step you should replace **domain** with **cloud** in order to select high level object

```
const makeSelectCloudName = () => createSelector(
  selectCloud,
 // Select high level cloud array
  (cloudState) => cloudState.get('cloud')
);
```

Comment: Still getting this error cloudState.get is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You should use only state just delete `.get('cloud')` part

`const selectCloud = (state) => state;`

`const makeSelectCloudName = () => createSelector( selectCloud, (cloudState) => cloudState.get('domain') );`

It worked for me!